# Celery Tasks not showing in Django Admin

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

[image]

I've followed the all the docs I could find as closely as I could, even setting up an example project using Celery's official django example ([celery/examples/django](https://github.com/celery/celery/tree/master/examples/django)) but tasks still aren't showing up in django-admin:

- https://github.com/mikeumus/django-celery-example

---

I've left a comment on a corresponding django-celery github issue here:

- https://github.com/celery/django-celery/issues/335

---

I've been 3 days trying to get tasks to show and to be able to use all the awesome code seen in django-celery's admin.py for things like scheduling tasks but I've had no luck. I'm running the the camera event deamon. Don't know what I'm missing. Someone in #celery IRC said django-celery is working for them so I must just be missing something. Really excited to get my isolated django-celery github project working so people can just clone it when using the module so that they don't miss anything in the checklist of little things required to get it working.

Django version 1.7.1
Celery 3.1.18

Here's my `./manage.py celery -A proj worker -l info --loglevel=DEBUG` and event camera output in a gist:

- https://gist.github.com/mikeumus/133631d3fa66ad53280c

---

Any advice is greatly appreciated. Anyone can access the ubuntu environment I'm working in via Cloud 9 here: https://ide.c9.io/mikeumus/celery-django-example
If you need write access, just ask for it here first.

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem.
As a workaround you can use flower that is a monitoring tool for celery.
http://flower.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Using flower you can see more information which is no provided for the admin site of django